# How to access freemarker objects in angular js or can i use angular instead of Freemarker

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, freemarker

How can i access values in freemarker using angularjs.i have  a map like this in freemarker which has bean .how can I use it in angular js?

Ex:`<#list dataMap["TRIGGER-JOBS"]["RE3"]["statusKey"] as espBean>`

How can I get values in this `dataMap` using angular js? or is there way I can use *only angular js* instead of freemarker.if so how? I am new to angular js guide me.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key is to realize, **where** and **when** each code is executed - Freemarker on the server when the page is requested and rendered (i.e. **before** the response is send to the browser) and Javascript (i.e. Angular) in the browser, **after** the browser receives the **already generated** response.

So if you want to combine these two together, you have to use Freemarker to generate valid Angular (HTML + Angular markup) code, which then will be processed browser-side. I.e. browser (Angular) knows nothing about how the page has been generated, and has no access to Freemarker variables - unless you have parsed them into HTML/JS code delivered in the response.

As for *is there way I can use only angular js instead of freemarker* - yes, there is. But the exact way depends on what you want to achieve. Usually, even in a full single-page application, you need some way to load/persist the data you work with, i.e. some kind of server back-end. This is usually done using some kind of (REST) web-services, so you shouldn't need Freemarker for that, but you would need some server code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to Angular and want to get started, I would suggest you use Angular Typescript. It's pretty simple to start up with. See the link

```
https://cli.angular.io/
```